# Angular ui-select in ng-grid

Tags: ng-grid, ui-select

I'm trying to use the ui-select dropdown inside an editable ng-grid. 
This is what my editable cell template looks like:-

```
editableCellTemplate: "<ui-select ng-model=\"COL_FIELD\" ng-class=\"'colt' + col.index\" theme=\"bootstrap\"><match placeholder=\"Choose client Account..\"></match><choices repeat=\"client in clients | filter: $select.search\"><div ng-bind-html=\"client.clientAccount | highlight: $select.search\"></div></choices></ui-select>"
```

However, I am not able to bind the selected value to the class,

> ng-class=\"'colt' + col.index\"

I am getting the following error on my console:

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' is an unexpected token
>   at column 20 of the expression ['colt' + col.index {open:
>   $select.open}] starting at [{open: $select.open}].

The HTML generated is as follows:

Basically the html is generated as ng-class="'colt' + col.index {open: $select.open}" and the curly braces produce a syntax error..

Anyone faced a similar problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add **';'** after the **'colt'+col.index** expression